# Select2 não funciona depois de clonar a section inteira

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

Depois de clonar uma section inteira, o select com select2 não funciona mais. Já tentei usar o destroy pra depois usar o select2 no JS mas não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar? Seria de grande valia. Obrigado.

**O elemento que eu clonei é uma section inteira, mas não está dando pra colocar aqui no editor do Stack Overflow. Então, antes dessa div que inicia o HTML tem uma section.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Telefone Principal</label>
            <input class="form-control clt fone"
                name="cltFone1"
                type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label">Telefone Secundário</label>
            <input class="form-control clt fone"
                name="cltFone2"
                type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cltInfoHide">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label">CPF</label>
                <input class="form-control cpf clt"
                    name="cltCpf"
                    type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>         
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>UF</label>
          <select class="select2" name="cltUf">
             <option value="" selected disabled>Estado</option>
             <option value="1">Acre</option>
             <option value="2">Alagoas</option>
             <option value="3">Amazonas</option>
             <option value="4">Amapá</option>
             <option value="5">Bahia</option>
             <option value="6">Ceará</option>
             <option value="7">Distrito Federal</option>
             <option value="8">Espírito Santo</option>
             <option value="9">Goiás</option>
             <option value="10">Maranhão</option>
             <option value="12">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
             <option value="13">Mato Grosso</option>
             <option value="11">Minas Gerais</option>
             <option value="14">Pará</option>
             <option value="15">Paraíba</option>
             <option value="18">Paraná</option>
             <option value="16">Pernambuco</option>
             <option value="17">Piauí</option>
             <option value="19">Rio de Janeiro</option>
             <option value="20">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
             <option value="23">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
             <option value="21">Rondônia</option>
             <option value="22">Roraima</option>
             <option value="24">Santa Catarina</option>
             <option value="26">São Paulo</option>
             <option value="25">Sergipe</option>
             <option value="27">Tocantins</option>
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Cidade</label>
          <select class="select2" name="cltCidade" disabled>
             <option value="" selected disabled>Cidade</option>
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.cltAdd', function() {

    //loop through each input
    var section = $('.cltSection:first').clone(true).find("input[name='cltNome[]']").each(function(){

            $(this).closest("section").find(".cltTrash").click();
            $(this).closest("section").find("input[name='cltFone1']").mask("destroy").mask('(00) 00000-0000');
            $(this).closest("section").find("input[name='cltFone2']").mask("destroy").mask('(00) 00000-0000');
            $(this).closest("section").find("input[name='cltCpf']").mask("destroy").mask('000.000.000-00');

            $(this).typeahead({
                input: "input[name='cltNome[]']",
                order: "asc",
                minLength: 1,
                display: ["nome"],
                source: {
                    partes: {
                        ajax: {
                            url: "modules/onelex/php/autocomplete_partes.php"
                        }
                    }
                }
                ,
                callback: {
                    onClick: function (node, a, item, event) {

                        var parte = item.id;

                        node.closest("section").find(".clt").prop("readonly", true);
                        node.closest("section").find(".cltLoad").show();
                        node.closest("section").find(".cltFind").hide();

                        $.getJSON("modules/onelex/php/parte.php?valor="+parte, function (dados){

                            if (dados.length > 0) {
                                $.each(dados, function(i, obj){
                                    fone1 = obj.fone1;
                                    fone2 = obj.fone2;
                                    email = obj.email;
                                    cpf = obj.cpf;
                                    rg = obj.rg;
                                    emissor = obj.emissor;
                                    endereco = obj.endereco;
                                    bairro = obj.bairro;
                                    numero = obj.numero;
                                    complemento = obj.complemento;
                                    uf = obj.uf;
                                    cidade = obj.cidade;
                                })
                                node.closest("section").find(".clt").prop("readonly", false);
                                node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltNome[]']").prop("readonly", true);
                                node.closest("section").find(".cltTrash").show();
                                node.closest("section").find(".cltLoad").hide();
                                node.closest("section").find(".cltFind").show().css("color","green");
                            } else {
                                node.closest("section").find(".clt").prop("readonly", false);
                                node.closest("section").find(".cltLoad").hide();
                                node.closest("section").find(".cltFind").show().text("\u2219 Erro ao localizar cliente").css("color","red");
                            }

                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltFone1']").val(fone1);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltFone2']").val(fone2);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltEmail']").val(email);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltCpf']").val(cpf);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltRg']").val(rg);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltEmissor']").val(emissor);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltEndereco']").val(endereco);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltBairro']").val(bairro);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltNumero']").val(numero);
                            node.closest("section").find("input[name='cltComplemento']").val(complemento);
                            node.closest("section").find("select[name='cltUf']").val(uf).change();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                              node.closest("section").find("select[name='cltCidade']").val(cidade).change();
                            }, 3000);
                        })

                    }
                },
                cancelButton: false
            });





    }).end()

    .insertAfter('.cltSection:last');
});
```

Já tentei colocar o

```
$(".select2").select2();
```

mas não funciona.`
Quando faço o descrito acima acontece o seguinte erro em imagens:

1 - Clico em "Adicionar Cliente"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2 - Aparecem dois selects na section que eu clonei. As duas funcionam iguais, ou seja, quando clico em uma a outra imita o valor. E a de baixo que foi adicionada não funciona nada, nem da pra clicar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já tentei inclusive colocar com o nome do select assim:

```
$(this).closest("section").find("select[name='cltUf']").select2();
```

Mas também não funciona.
Já tentei usar o destroy pra depois chamar de novo a função assim:

```
$(this).closest("section").find("select[name='cltUf']").select2("destroy").select2();
```

Mas também não funciona.
Não sei o que pode ser. Acho que o problema não está sendo no select em si. Mas sim na hora de clonar a Section.

Desde já agradeço aqueles que tentaram me ajudar aqui.
Ainda não tenho a solução. Quando descobrir eu posto aqui.
Obrigado.

Comment: Após o `.insertAfter('.cltSection:last');` adicione essa linha  `$(".select2").select2();`

Comment: tal como o caique disse, depois de clonar e adicionar o html, tens que executar novamente o comando do select2

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso! Acontece uma coisa que eu não consigo entender. Vou editar a postagem pra vocês entenderem melhor e tentar me ajudar. Obrigado.